# How to derive the data after regressing out covariates?

Tags: r, regression

I have some physiological data that I would like to remove the gender & age effects from it.  I used the model in R

```
lm(Measure~Physio+Age+Gender)
```

My question is for the next stage of analysis I would like to use the Measure without the gender & age effects.  Which outcome variable of lm should I be using?

Comment: What _is_ the next stage of analysis anyway? It's relevant for answering this in a way that will be helpful

Comment: Two things I have in mind: (1) To fit a model to the physiological data with the gender & age effects removed.  That can be done by regression? (2) To compare two groups of people in terms of their treatment received, but without gender & age effects (which is correlated with the physiological data).  Thanks!

Comment: So for #2 you want to _control for_ gender and age? Is "Physio" the treatment? What do you mean by "removed?"

Comment: Indeed for #2, I would like to control for gender and age.  Physiological data are the EEG measures obtained, which may be described by a histogram for each subject.  I would like to model this histogram controlling for age and gender effects.  Apologies, by "removed" I meant "control for gender and age".

Comment: what do you mean by "model this histogram"?

Comment: To fit a model to the histogram.

Comment: No offense, but this is starting to sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/269241). What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: @TTZ were you able to solve it? I too want to regress out the effect of age from gene expression and retrieve expression values with no age effect. Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the residuals from your model, they are the bit left over after you subtract out the predicted values. Handily R has a `resid()` extractor function for you to save you the hassle of working it out yourself. If you did want to see the predicted values for some reason it is no surprise that there is a `predict()` method for `lm` objects.

Comment: Are you sure that's what they're asking for? It looks to me like they want a posterior prediction from `model <- lm(Measure~Age+Gender)`, i.e. `m <- fitted(model); s <- summary(model)$sigma; rnorm(length(m), m, s)`. That would be an approximate expected distribution of Measure by "integrating out" age and gender. This is not at all the same thing as the residual.

Comment: @ssdecontrol that is a good point. Perhaps it is worth posting it as an alternative answer?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Many thanks for pointing out! Is it correct that rnorm(length(m), m, s) returns the distribution that has age and gender covariates removed?  Would "m" be the measures that have age and gender covariates removed?

Comment: (+1 to the post as well as the two comments - apparently I am the only upvoter in this thread!) I think that this is a bit of a philosophical point. In the case we analyse the residuals we take the stance that all `X` variables "add up" to give us the final `Measure`. In the case of analysing the "*approximate expected distribution*" we assume that the variables `X` determine `Measure` and given enough of them `Measure` should be perfectly determined. Pick your poison...

Comment: @usεr11852 i suppose it comes down to how literally you want to interpret the term "subtract". I'll post my comment as an answer when I'm no longer posting from my phone.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Cool; I am looking forward to it! (I think that the most important consequence is that as var$(E(Y|Z) \le$ var$(Y)$ you will immediately have a shrinkage-like effect to your analysis but I will wait for your post on the matter!